# Generalized formula for third point to form an equilateral triangle

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, complex-geometry

We know two complex numbers $z_A,z_B$ corresponding to points $A$ and $B$ in the complex plane. We need to generally find $z_C$ corresponding to point $C$ such that $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral.

Note: $\exists~2$ points $C_1$ and $C_2$ that satisfy the condition.

[image: I drew this picture]

We know that in an equilateral triangle $h=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}l$. We have to go from the middle point $M~~\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|\vec{AB}|$ either up or down.

Let $O\in\mathcal{P}$.

$\vec{OC}=\vec{OM}+\vec{MC}$

$\vec{OM}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{OA}+\vec{OB})$

We are left to find $\vec{MC}$.

$\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$ are the unit vectors of $O_x$ and $O_y$ respectively

$\vec{BA}\cdot\vec{i}=|\vec{AB}|\cdot|\vec{i}|\cdot cos\alpha$

$((x_A-x_B)\vec{i}+(y_A-y_B)\vec{j})\cdot\vec{i}=|\vec{AB}|\cdot cos\alpha$

$x_A-x_B=|\vec{AB}|\cdot cos\alpha\Rightarrow cos\alpha=\frac{x_A-x_B}{|\vec{AB}|}$

$|\vec{BA}\times\vec{i}|=|\vec{AB}|\cdot|\vec{i}|\cdot sin\alpha$

$|((x_A-x_B)\vec{i}+(y_A-y_B)\vec{j})\times\vec{i}|=|\vec{AB}|\cdot sin\alpha$

$|y_A-y_B|=|\vec{AB}|\cdot sin\alpha\Rightarrow sin\alpha=\frac{|y_A-y_B|}{|\vec{AB}|}$

$sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=cos\alpha\Rightarrow sin\theta=cos\alpha$

$cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=sin\alpha\Rightarrow cos\theta=sin\alpha$

$\vec{MC}=\pm|\vec{MC}|(cos\theta\cdot\vec{i}+sin\theta\cdot\vec{j})$ (we have $\pm$ because we can go either up or down)

$|\vec{MC}|=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|\vec{AB}|$

$\vec{MC}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|\vec{AB}|(\frac{|y_A-y_B|}{|\vec{AB}|}\vec{i}+\frac{x_A-x_B}{|\vec{AB}|}\vec{j})$

$\vec{MC}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(|y_A-y_B|\vec{i}+(x_A-x_B)\vec{j})$

$\vec{OC}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{OA}+\vec{OB})\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(|y_A-y_B|\vec{i}+(x_A-x_B)\vec{j})$

Transforming into a complex equation we get:

$z_C=\frac{1}{2}(z_A+z_B)\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(|Im(z_A)-Im(z_B)|+(Re(z_A)-Re(z_B))i)$

However, this does not seem to work when I graphically represent the points (I use Desmos). What do I do wrong?

I need this to simulate the Koch snowflake fractal. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azBNsPa1WC4&ab_channel=KhanAcademy.

EDIT:

I've figured out what I did wrong. I did not consider $\alpha$ in the trigonometrical sense. The marked answer inspired me to solve the problem using the Euler formula.

To find $\alpha$ we have to imagine a translation such that $A$ is in the center of the orthogonal axis. We will consider $\alpha=\angle(\vec{AB};\vec{i})$ in the trigonometrical sense with $\alpha\in[-\pi;\pi]$. Hence,

$cos\alpha=\frac{Re(z_2)-Re(z_1)}{|z_2-z_1|}$

$sin\alpha=\frac{Im(z_2)-Im(z_1)}{|z_2-z_1|}$

We need to rotate $B$ from $\vec{AB}$ to the left (counter-clockwise) or to the right (clockwise) $\pm\frac{\pi}{3}$. Let's first consider the $+$ case.

$\delta=\alpha+\frac{\pi}{3}$

$cos\delta=cos(\alpha+\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{Re(z_2)-Re(z_1)}{|z_2-z_1|}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot\frac{Im(z_2)-Im(z_1)}{|z_2-z_1|}$

$sin\delta=sin(\alpha+\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{Im(z_2)-Im(z_1)}{|z_2-z_1|}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot\frac{Re(z_2)-Re(z_1)}{|z_2-z_1|}$

Let $\vec{r}$ be the unit vector oriented to the angle after the rotation.

$r=e^{i\delta}=cos\delta+i\cdot sin\delta=\frac{1}{2|z_2-z_1|}\Big(\big(\underbrace{Re(z_2)+i\cdot Im(z_2)}_{z_2}\big)-\big(\underbrace{Re(z_1)+i\cdot Im(z_1)}_{z_1}\big)+\sqrt{3}\big(\underbrace{i\cdot Re(z_2)-Im(z_2)}_{iz_2}\big)-\sqrt{3}\big(\underbrace{i\cdot Re(z_1)-Im(z_1)}_{iz_1}\big)\Big)$

$r=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{z_2-z_1}{|z_2-z_1|}\cdot(1+i\sqrt{3})$

$z_3=z_1+|z_2-z_1|r$

$z_3=z_1+\frac{1}{2}(z_2-z_1)(1+i\sqrt{3})$

As for the $-$ case we are similarly going to get

$z_3=z_1+\frac{1}{2}(z_2-z_1)(1-i\sqrt{3})$

FINAL ANSWER

$\mathbf{z_3=z_1+(\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)(z_2-z_1)}$

And what's most interesting to it is that $\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ turns out to be $-\omega$, where $\omega=\sqrt[3]{1}~$, the primitive cube root of unity.

So we can clearly say that

$\mathbf{z_3=z_1+\omega(z_1-z_2),~\omega\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}}$

EDIT2: I've just finished the project.

Here is the source code:

https://github.com/s1mplex-Neox/Koch/blob/main/koch.cpp

Here is the video:

https://youtu.be/cyuEGvcgLY8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this problem. Try this approach: let $\alpha=\angle(z2-z1)$. The the third point to create an equilateral triangle is given by

$$z_3=z_2+|z_2-z_1|e^{i(\pi+\alpha-\pi/3)}$$

Comment: Your answer gave me a strong suggestion to discover the generalized formula. I don't know how I couldn't come up with the Euler formula. I'll edit the post to show what I've done.

Comment: @Neox I find that you are still making this too complicated. Moreover, I find the final answer does not give correct results numerically/graphically for random $z_{1,2}$ on the plane,

Comment: Can you please give me an example that gives incorrect results according to my final formula?

Comment: I've just created a C++ program that calculates $z_3$ according to my formula and calculates the distances between $A$, $B$ and $C$. They are always equal. Do you want me to show you the code?

Comment: Also, you said that I am overcomplicating it. I just want to remind you that I need an **exact** answer, not something with $e^{i...}$, since I'm working on a project to simulate  a fractal and I must plug in numerical coordinates.

Comment: My apologies, I programmed it up incorrectly. As to your second statement, about $e^{i...}$, I program in Matlab, which handles complex numbers seamlessly.

Comment: I understand it now, I think I'll try Matlab too if it can handle such things. By the way, I finished up the project, I'll publish the code and a short video and I'll share the links in a few minutes. Basically I created a class to interpret complex numbers and make operations with them, then a function to convert a complex number into a SFML Vector and such I was able to draw vertices between points. I programmed the Koch snowflake iteratively because SFML doesn't allow you to put it down recursively :/

Answer (score 0):

Direct approach: $|z_c-z_b|=|z_c-z_a|=|z_a-z_b|$ Leading to:

$x_c^2+y_c^2-2(x_ax_c+y_ay_c)=x_b^2+y_b^2-2(x_ax_b+y_ay_b)$
$x_c^2+y_c^2-2(x_bx_c+y_by_c)=x_a^2+y_a^2-2(x_ax_b+y_ay_b)$

Solve for $x_c$ and $y_c$.  Solution approach.  Combine equation to eliminate $x_c^1+y_c^2$ to get linear relation between $x_c$ and $y_c$.  Plug into one of original pair to get quadratic.  There are obviously two possible solutions

Comment: Hi. At first glance I tried your approach and I also got a system of a linear and a quadratic equation, but it was pretty hard to solve it and get a generalized formula. I would be very thankful if you could tell me where my mistake is.

Comment: I have difficulty plowing through what you did.  However using your basic idea I would suggest the following.  Get the straight line through $z_a$ and $z_b$ It will look like $y=mx+b$, where $m=\frac{y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}$ and $b=y_m-mx_m$ with $z_m=\frac{z_a+z_b}{2}$ Then the two solutions you want are along a line $y=\frac{-x}{m}+c$ where $c=y_m+\frac{x_m}{m}$.