# Condition that a polygon is regular in the complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, polygons, roots-of-unity

In [Generalized formula for third point to form an equilateral triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185491/generalized-formula-for-third-point-to-form-an-equilateral-triangle/4186194?noredirect=1#comment8681316_4186194) I deduced that for $A(z_1)$ and $B(z_2)$ the formula for $C(z_3)$ such that $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral has the formula:

$z_3=z_1+\omega(z_1-z_2),~\omega^3=1,~\omega\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$

Rearranging we get

$(\omega+1)z_1-z_3-\omega z_2=0$

Multiply by $\omega$

$(\omega^2+\omega)z_1-\omega z_3-\omega^2z_2=0$

$\omega^3-1=0\Rightarrow(\omega-1)(\omega^2+\omega+1)=0$ and since $\omega\ne1,~\omega^2+\omega+1=0\Rightarrow\omega^2+\omega=-1$

$-z_1-\omega z_3-\omega^2z_2=0$

Multiply by -1

$z_1+\omega z_3+\omega^2z_2=0$

Generally we have this equation:

$z_1+\omega z_2+\omega^2z_3=0$

Is this valid for n-th sided regular polygons? That means,

**A polygon is regular if and only if**

$\mathbf{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n z_k\omega_k=0}$ **($\omega$ is the n-th root of unity, $\omega_k$ is the k-th such root)**

**where the vertices of the polygon are** $\mathbf{A_k(z_k)}$.

I attempted to prove it by translating the polygon such that the center coincides with the origin of the orthogonal axis but I got stuck.

EDIT:

I've dwelt on this problem last night and based on @Jean Marie's demonstration I thought of a more practical proof for the implication regular polygon $\Rightarrow$ sum $= 0$.

Let $A_1A_2A_3(...)A_n$ be a regular polygon with $A_k(z_k)$ **in trigonometrical order** and $G(z_G)$ be the center of gravity of the polygon.

We will prove $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n z_k\omega_k=0$ by subtracting $(z_G\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \omega_k)$.

$LHS=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \big((z_k-z_G)\omega_k\big)$

$RHS=-z_G\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \omega_k=0$, since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \omega_k=0$

We are left to prove

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \big((z_k-z_G)\omega_k\big)=0$

Consider $C_k(z_k-z_G)$.

Regular polygon $C_1C_2C_3(...)C_n$ is obtained by translating $A_1A_2A_3(...)A_k$ such that the center of gravity coincides with the origin of the orthogonal axis.

$C_1,~C_2,~C_3,~(...)~C_n$ will be points on the circle with radius $=$ the circumradius of the polygon.

Also consider $C_k'\big((z_k-z_G)\omega_k\big)$.

$C_k'$ is obtained from $C_k$ by circular rotations.

For n - odd : $C_1'C_2'C_3'(...)C_n'$ is regular polygon (1) $\Rightarrow$ the relation is obvious.

For n - even : $C_1'C_2'C_3'(...)C_{n/2}'$ and $C_{n/2+1}'C_{n/2+2}'(...)C_n'$ are regular polygons (2) $\Rightarrow$

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n/2}\big((z_k-z_G)\omega_k\big)=0$

$\sum\limits_{k=n/2+1}^n\big((z_k-z_G)\omega_k\big)=0$

Summing up the equations we get the equation that was left to prove.

We need to prove that

(1) For a set $S$ with n elements, n odd, if for every index $k$ (counting from $0$) we "mark" the element with index $2k+1~mod~n$, then every element of $S$ is going to be marked.

(2) For a set $S$ with n elements, n even, if for every index $k$ (counting from $0$) we "mark" the element with index $2k+1~mod~n$, then elements with odd indexes will be marked twice.

How can I prove these statements using modular mathematics?

Comment: "*And by symmetry...*" — That may need some clarification. The two relations do not both hold, and which one does in fact hold depends on the orientation of the triangle.

Comment: @dxiv By symmetry I mean if we know the other two vertices and we need to find the other one.

Comment: Given two vertices $z_{1,2}$, there are 2 other points $z_3$ which "complete" an equilateral triangle. The triangle $z_1z_2z_3$ is clockwise in one case, counterclockwise in the other case. Each of those solutions satisfies *one* of the two relations you wrote, but not *both*. The usual way to cover both cases in one equation is to write $z_1+\omega z_2+\omega^2 z_3=0$ where $\omega$ is one of the complex cubic roots of unity, without specifying which one.

Comment: @dxiv My point was that after finding $z_3$, it doesn't matter in what order you write the equation, it's always going to be true. That is, the implication is reversal in the case of the equilateral triangle as regular polygon.

Comment: My point is that "***and*** *by symmetry*" is misleading. That's not an "*and*", since *both* relations cannot be true at the same time. It's one *or* the other.

Comment: @dxiv My phrasing was wrong, I get it now. Check the edit + maybe you can help me out with the last statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a necessary and sufficient condition.

- The implication : "points $z_k$s are the vertices of a regular polygon" (assumed indexed in the trigonometric order) implies "sum = $0$" is true.

Indeed the vertices of a regular $n$-gon are the images of the "standard" regular $n$-gon using this "similitude"

$$s(z)=A(z-z_G) \ \ \text{with} \ \ A=re^{i \theta } \ \ \text{and} \ \ z_G=\frac1n \sum z_k \tag{1}$$

where $\theta$ is the rotation angle, $r$ is the enlargment/shrinking factor and $z_G$ is the barycenter of points $z_k$.

Relationship (1) can be expressed in a slightly different way:

$$s(z)=Az+B$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^n z_k \omega_n^k=\sum_{k=1}^n s(\omega_n^k) \omega_n^k=\sum_{k=1}^n (A\omega_n^k +B) \omega_n^k$$

$$=A\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n \omega_n^{2k}}_0 +B \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n \omega_n^k}_0=0\tag{2}$$

The fact that the first summation in (2) is zero is a consequence of a more general result one can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/642173). A specific proof could also be given by distinguishing the cases $n$ odd/$n$ even.

- Whereas, in the other direction, "sum=$0$" doesn't imply "points $z_k$ constitute a regular polygon".

Here is a counterexample for $n=4$ with $w_4=i$ :

$$z_1=0+0i,\ \ z_2=3-2i, \ \ z_3=-1+2i, \ \ z_4=1-3i$$

their sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^4 z_k \omega_4^k=(0)i+(3-2i)i^2+(-1+2i)i^3+(1-3i)i^4$$

$$=-(3-2i)-i(-1+2i)+(1-3i)=0$$

whereas the $z_k$ aren't the vertices of a square.

[image]

Fig 1: Case $n=8$: A "continuous" mapping of the regular octagon made by the $w_8^k$s onto the regular octagon of the $z_k$s. The "continuous" aspect is of course unimportant ; I have used it because of its aesthetical appeal.

Matlab program of the figure:

```
    n=8;
    z=exp((i*2*pi/n)*(0:n));
    A=@(t)(t);B=@(t)(1-exp(i*(t-1)));
    for t=1:0.1:4
       plot(A(t)*z+B(t));
    end;
```

Comment: This proves that I'm wrong. It seems like it's a coincidence for the equilateral triangle. I also doubt the other implication (if it's a regular polygon, then the sum = 0). Thank you for the counterexample!

Comment: How I tried: $z_G=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n z_k$, where $z_G$ is the center of mass. Multiply by n and move $nz_G$ to the right side of the equation and we get to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (z_k-z_G)=0$. Notice that $z_k-z_G\in\mathcal{C}(O,R)$ where $R$ is the circumradius of the polygon. That would be the link to roots of unity. But I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: I've just seen the edit! In $s(z)$ why do we have to multiply by $z$ if we have already scaled and rotated it accordingly ($re^{i\theta}$)?

Comment: We have to use $z$ because wz must have a function $f(z)=Az+B$ where $z$ will take values $z=w_n^k, \ $ for $k=1,2...n$.

Comment: See the reference I just added.

Comment: It's crystal clear now. So to get from the roots of unity to the regular polygon that is randomly positioned on the plane we have to multiply them with a complex number with absolute value equal to one (rotate them) and add another complex number that is the center of gravity of the polygon. And if we use this algebraic trick we cancel things out and we get 0. I'll look up the link you added tomorrow, because now I'm tired. Thank you A LOT for your help!

Comment: I've just made an edit to the question you can check it if you want.

Comment: 1) I thought you were mentionning an Edit of mine. 2) Honestly (pardon my frankness) I have some difficulty to see the point of this edit, besides showing how $z_G$ is "acting". 3) I have attempted on my side to improve the presentation of my answer, in particular by showing how transformations $s(z)=Az+B$ are "acting".

Comment: Regarding 2) I was just obsessed to fully understand the way the polygon is transformed and I felt like I had to write the complete explanation somewhere :) Your answer already encapsulates the proof which I've agreed on and understood, no need to make a special edit! There's no problem with your proof, but I wanted to deeply understand those "rotations" that take place with $s(z)$ and have it written somewhere. Also, I find interesting the way this problem links to modular mathematics, although I couldn't find a full proof for (1). For (2) we know that odd mod even is always odd.

Comment: And btw, I looked up the link with powers of $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Working in the complex plane throughout ...

Let $R_{n,k}$ be the "standard" regular $\{n/k\}$-gon (that is, the regular polygon with [Schläfli symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol#Regular_polygons_(plane)) $\{n/k\}$ (where we leave the fraction un-reduced, and we allow $k=0$), whose vertices are at $\omega_n^{mk}$ for $m=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, and where $\omega_n$ is the principal $n$-th root of unity. (These vertices follow Grünbaum's convention, not depicted in Wikipedia, when $n$ and $k$ are not relatively prime. For instance, wikipedia shows $\{8/2\}$ as two squares overlapping at an angle; Grünbaum's convention considers $\{8/2\}$ to be a single $\{4/1\}$ square, *traversed twice*.) Here are the $\{5/k\}$-gons:

[image]

Both $R_{5,1}$ and $R_{5,4}$ are "regular convex pentagons" (and both $R_{5,2}$ and $R_{5,3}$ are "regular pentagrams"), but their opposing orientations are important here. Note that $R_{5,0}$'s vertices all coincide at $1+0i$, but there are still five of them.

For an $n$-gon $P$, let $[P]$ be the vector of its vertices (taken in order around the polygon)
$$[P]:=(p_0, p_1, p_2,\ldots, p_{n-1})$$
As it happens, we can write *uniquely*
$$[P] = a_0 [R_{n,0}] + a_1 [R_{n,1}] + \cdots + a_{n-1} [R_{n,n-1}] \tag{1}$$
for appropriate complex coefficients $a_k$. (Proof: Equating individual vector components gives a linear system of $n$ equations in the $n$ unknowns $a_k$.) Observe that each $a_k [R_{n,k}]$ is the vertex-vector of a scaled-and-rotated copy of $R_{n,k}$; this says that

> Any $n$-gon is a "vertex sum" of $n$ regular $\{n/k\}$-gons (one for each $k$).

Because the centroid of polygons $R_{n,k}$ for $k\neq 0$ are at the origin, the centroid of $P$ (ie, the polygon's *location* in the plane) is determined by the $R_{n,0}$ term. On the other hand, the *shape* of $P$ is determined by those $k\neq 0$ terms, and we can say

> $P$ is a regular $\{n/k\}$-gon, for $k\neq 0$, if and only if $a_k\neq 0$, and $a_m=0$ for $0<m\neq k$.

If we only care about *non-oriented* shapes, we can test whether $P$ is an $\{n/k\}$-gon or an $\{n/(n-k)\}$-gon; ie,

> $P$ is a *non-oriented* regular $\{n/k\}$-gon, for $k\neq 0$, if and only if $a_m\neq0$ for $m=k$ or $m=n-k$ (but not both, unless $k=n/2$), and $a_m=0$ for all other $m>0$.

Now, OP's summation with roots of unity, call it $S_1(P)$, amounts to the *dot product* of a polygon's vertex-vector with that of $R_{n,1}$. Considering more-generally the dot product with vertex-vector of $R_{n,k}$, we have, invoking the decomposition $(1)$,
$$S_k(P) := [P]\cdot [R_{n,k}] = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j [R_{n,j}]\cdot [R_{n,k}] \tag{2}$$
But $$[R_{n,j}]\cdot [R_{n,k}]=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \omega_n^{mj} \omega_n^{mk}=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\left(\omega_n^{j+k}\right)^m=\begin{cases}
n, & j+k=0 \pmod{n} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} \tag{3}$$
Therefore, $(2)$ reduces to
$$S_k(P) = n a_{n-k} \tag{4}$$
(In the case of $k=0$, we take $a_{n-0}=a_0$.) Therefore, the test for (oriented) regularity becomes

> $P$ is a regular $\{n/k\}$-gon if and only if $S_{n-k}(P)\neq 0$, and $S_m(P)=0$ for $0<m\neq n-k$.

For non-oriented regularity:

> $P$ is a non-oriented regular $\{n/k\}$-gon if and only if $S_m(P)\neq0$ for $m=k$ or $m=n-k$ (but not both, unless $k=n/2$), and $S_m(P)=0$ for all other $m>0$.

In the case of a triangle $T$, decomposition $(1)$ is simply
$$[T] = a_0[R_{3,0}] + a_1[R_{3,1}]+ a_2[R_{3,2}] \tag{1.3}$$
OP's test for regularity (that is, *equilaterality*) amounts to checking whether $S_1(T)=0$, which corresponds to whether the $R_{3,2}$ component of $(1)$ vanishes. This is consistent with the *oriented* test given above. For a non-oriented test, we'd check that $S_1(T)=0$ or $S_2(T)=0$ (but not both).

So, for general polygons, OP was correct to suspect a connection (congratulations on the insight!), but simply didn't allow for enough tests.

---

The ideas here are captured in a modified theorem of Barlotti. Barlotti observed that any $n$-gon is a "vertex sum" of *affinely-regular* non-oriented $\{n/k\}$-gons (with $0\leq k\leq n/2$). And it happens that, for $k\neq0$ and $k\neq n/2$, an affinely-regular $\{n/k\}$-gon is itself the vertex sum of oppositely-oriented *actually*-regular ones, so that we get a sum ($(1)$ above) with an $\{n/k\}$ component for each $0\leq k\leq n-1$.

(One can also write any polyhedron as a "vertex sum" of combinatorially-equivalent "symmetric" polyhedra. The nature of the "symmetric" components, and how many there are, depend upon eigen-analysis of the adjacency matrix of the polyhedron's vertex-and-edge skeleton. Likewise in higher dimensions. But I digress ...)

An interesting related result is a generalization of [Napoleon's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem):

> Given an oriented $n$-gon, erect an $\{n/k\}$-gon, for some $k$, on each edge, and connect their centroids in order to create a new oriented polygon. (Note that if $k=0$, the new polygon matches the old, so we could ignore it.) On the sides of *that* polygon, erect $\{n/k\}$-gons, for a different $k$; iterate.
>
> After $n-1$ steps (or $n-2$ steps, if we're ignoring $k=0$), *the resulting polygon will be a **regular** $\{n/k\}$-gon*, for the leftover value of $k$!
>
> As it happens, the order of the $k$s used in the iteration doesn't matter.

Napoleon's Theorem for an oriented triangle (ignoring $k=0$) erects $\{3/1\}$-triangles on the sides to get a regular $\{3/2\}$-triangle; and erects $\{3/2\}$-triangles on the sides to get a regular $\{3/1\}$-triangle. (The two results are the "inner" and "outer" Napoleon triangles. Which is which depends upon how the original triangle is oriented.) Likewise, the iterative process above associates with every $n$-gon a regular "leftover" $\{n/k\}$-gon for every $k$ ... kinda like the decomposition $(1)$. However, these Napoleonic polygons do not typically match the size and/or rotation of the components in $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! At first glance this seems pretty heavy math for me but I'll check everything tomorrow and give a feedback.